# Nuke OFX plugin – Custom Icon

Tags: python, c++, bundle, nuke, ofx

My question deals with the customisation of icons in the NUKE GUI. I know that `menu.py` file in C:\Program Files\Nuke11.2v3\plugins can archive locally such goal for a personal Gizmo.

But in my case, I have set my environment variable `OFX_PLUGIN_PATH` to `C:\OFX_PLUGIN_PATH` where I store various OFX bundles, each with the appropriated hierarchy (`Contents`, `Resources`, `Win64` directories) and its own icon.

All my bundles belong to the same Group:

```
mDeclarePluginFactory(MyPluginFactory, {}, {});
void MyPluginFactory::describe(OFX::ImageEffectDescriptor& desc)
{
  ...
  desc.setPluginGrouping(PLUGIN_GROUPING);
  ...
}
```

It works fine. When I launch NUKE, it parse the `OFX_PLUGIN_PATH`, found all the bundles, display on the left menu all the discovered bundles in a same Group, with the correct icons.

My question is: how can I customise the group icon (I do not need the default icon)? Preferably with a mechanism inside the bundles hierarchy, and not locally, for distribution purpose.

[image]

Thanks!